# I have issue regarding tableView. Value change on scroll

Tags: swift, uitableview, ios9.2

I have issue regarding tableView. I am working on a project in swift on chat module. I am getting the data from the web service. For the first time when the view is load my chat cells appear perfect. But as I send a message or scroll the tableView the value changes or lost. Can anyone help me with this please. I stuck on this issue for a long time.

Comment: Can you post the code you're using?

Answer (score 1):

I have answer regarding tableView. *scnr*.

You need to track changes to your data in you tableView's `dataSource` as well an the tableView itself.

**Edit**:
Assuming your chat data is an array of strings, sorted by date, newest message on top, on inserting data, you should

```
tableView?.beginUpdates() // signal the tableview a pending update
data.insert(newMessage, atIndex:0) // modify your dataSource's data
tableView?.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(0, inSection: 0)], withRowAnimation: .Automatic) // insert the new row in the tableView
tableView?.endUpdates() // commit changes
```

Comment: can you explain it a bit more

Comment: I did edit my answer to include assumtions about code missing in the question and some swift.

Answer (score 0):

Your data source should be co-ordinated with the tableView index .i.e there should be a rule to figure out the message that should be displayed given and IndexPath of the tableView. The simplest rule is the following assuming your tableView consists of only 1 section, the indexOf message in your dataSource should be equal to the IndexPath.Row. For example, you are sending a new message which should be added to the bottom of your tableView

```
dataSource.append(newMessage)
tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(0, inSection: 0)], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
```

and in your cellForRowAtIndexPath delegate method

```
let message = dataSource[indexPath.row]
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MessageCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
// then use the message to populate the cell then return cell

return cell
```